# Ricardian Contract

Tags: smart-contract, eosio.cdt, ricardian, signing

Does eosio also sign the transaction with the ricardian contract of user consent and/or how does the application proove that a party agreed on said ricardian contract?

I have integrated the ricardian contract with the ricardian template toolkit but do I have to save the user's consent? Because how would the application proove validity if the ricardian contract in the ABI file changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everytime you update the ABI file, a record is stored on chain. The action is `eosio::setabi`. Therefore it would be possible to say which version of the ABI file was current on the blockchain at the time of a transaction being signed.